# Which stack for online 3D rendering?

Tags: 3d, nvidia, maya, 3dsmax, 3d-rendering

We are looking for a solution where we can render photorealistic 3D product images on a webserver or in the cloud.

Basically we want to create one 3D model per product and render it with different textures for creating all product images. Since the amount of combinations is quite huge and textures might be created on demand, pre-rendering them offline is no solution.

We tried creating models in Cinema 4D/Maya and rendering them with migenius RealityServer (iRay). Unfortunately we are facing compatibility issues when exporting to .mi files for migenius renderer.

Any other technology stack proposal? Is there any renderer which can be used server-side?

**Requirements:**

- photorealistic
- image output (e.g. JPEG)
- server based
- any mainstream 3D tool for creating assets
- command-based/API based exchange of textures

**Soft requirements:**

- fast render times
- no enterprise pricing

Looking forward to any ideas!

Comment: This site is for coding and programming related questions. Try this site for this kind d of question instead: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advide. I will repost the question there. Since we developed a wrapper for migenius renderer, I thought about it in a more development focused task. But you are probably right!